# Visual Studio Python: How do I build a connection string using passed in arguments?

Tags: python, visual-studio, pyodbc

Fellow techies,

To make a long story short, I want to pass in configuration arguments from an SSIS package to a python program (script below).

```
#app and sql server specific settings
ssisTimespan = sys.argv[1]
ssisIoTDatabase = sys.argv[2]
ssisIoTserver = sys.argv[3]

#[snippet]
AuditTableConnString =  '"' + "Driver={SQL Server};" + '"' + ' ' + '"' + "Server=" + ssisIoTserver + ';"' + ' ' + '"' + "Database=" + ssisIoTDatabase + ';"' + ' ' + '"' + "Trusted_Connection=yes;" + '"' + "autocommit=True;" + '"'


LoadAuditconn = pyodbc.connect(AuditTableConnString)
```

The line above errors out with:
*('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')*

So rather than interpret the AuditTableConnString as is (screen shot), the value is taken to be the intended target server. I can see how that would happen.

[image]

What do I need to do to keep the server and database names configurable when building out a flexible connection string?

Comment: After @bigmacd offered a better formatted string, creating the odbc connection fails in the same way. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

```
AuditTableConnString = string.Format("Driver={{SQL Server}};Server={0};Database={1};Trusted_Connection=yes;autocommit=True;", ssisIoTserver, ssisIoTDatabase);
```

Comment: Thanks @bigmacd, I'll give it a try.

Comment: There is a small change: You have to escape the curly braces in string.format using {{ and }}.  Sorry, I'll edit the above answer

Comment: it looks like in the end, the LoadAuditTableConnString = pyodbc.connect(AuditTableConnString) still fails in the same way.

Comment: bigmacd's syntax was slightly off: Here is what finally worked: AuditTableConnString = "Driver={{SQL Server}};Server={0};Database={1};Trusted_Connection=yes;autocommit=True;".format(str(ssisIoTserver), str(ssisIoTDatabase))